# Generic Cross-client Authorization workflow

Tags: google-oauth

How / can I get Google cross-client auth to work in a client-type-agnostic way (e.g., using only a web browser and cURL commands)?

I have two OAuth 2.0 clients (let's call them Client A and Client B), both of type "Web Application" and in the same [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) project. Each client's credentials is used by a different app (say, Apps A & B, respectively):

**App A** implements Google Sign-In using Client A; the ID token obtained after a user signs in is sent to a `/verify` endpoint, which verifies the token and authenticates the user to the app.

**App B** wants to automate the offline authentication of a specific user to *App A* by sending an ID token (obtained using *Client B*'s credentials) directly to its `/verify` endpoint. (Note that *App B* doesn't have access to *Client A*'s secret.) The general strategy is:

1. manually get a one-time-use auth code for the user (using proper scopes and `access_type=offline`),
2. exchange it for tokens (requires client secret),
3. securely store the refresh token and use it to generate ID tokens whenever I want, which I'll in turn use to authenticate the user to App A.

If *App B* uses tokens obtained in the "normal" way using *Client B* credentials, then *App A* will see my ID token as invalid, since the standard check involves verifying that the decoded token's payload has an `aud` value equal to *Client A*'s ID, which it won't.

Cross-client identity/auth to the rescue, right?

From https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth:

> Google considers that when a user has granted access to a particular scope to **any client ID in a project**, the grant indicates the user's trust in the **whole application** for that scope.
>
> The effect is that the user should not be prompted to approve access to any resource more than once for the same logical application, whenever the components of the application can be reliably authenticated by Google's authorization infrastructure, which today **includes web clients, JavaScript clients, and Android apps.**

*(Emphasis mine.)*

## The Problem

The problem is that, while the docs explicitly say that what I want to do is possible, it only shows an example for Android -> Web cross-client auth, which involves calling a specific utility function available only on Android, passing the scope as a "magic string" of the form `oauth2:server:client_id:{CLIENT_A_ID}:api_scope:{SCOPE1 SCOPE2 ...}`.

I've scoured the internet and have found zero examples of how to do this in a generic way or for other client combinations. I've tried naively sending a similarly-constructed "magic" scope string when requesting an auth code, which is seen as an invalid by Google's servers (`invalid_scope` 400 error). I've stopped just short of decompiling Google libraries to see how it translates this string into actual server requests (if that's, in fact, what it's doing).

My question: **Does anyone know how to get Google cross-client auth to work in a client-type-agnostic way?** (Or at least in the specific way I'm asking?)

Comment: I have tried to get this to work before.  Basically using a windows console application and a website.   Again Not using any android app.   I came to the opinion that Google has some code imbedded google magic in the Android stuff that allows for this.  I could find no way to get it work.  Nor could I find any documentation that or information about anyone actually getting it to work.